# Modifying the Width of a Symbol Mark in Vega

Tags: vega

I want to label the symbols in my Vega graph. Some of the labels are long, extending beyond the boundaries of my symbols. How do I extend the width of a symbol to handle long labels?

Update: Is there a way of increasing the width of a symbol mark?

This is a [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAE4tvIC0AGxriA1ttk0kZRUgTaA7nRjaAZm0VQ4Bq4rhQmHCy2kZIAJ5sDJhSlnA4NIGmZNqwSHaBcIqpbAZsUFAMiv7i3tqm2vRwumykRtoAMgraALI0EACXdkxGCpTSIM6y9GgA7AAM4zLwNGRYaAKTMkjRbBA0AF5waCA4SLID62TiSEYQaADaoCcI2+h68gBK+zQM5zLEpwx3izJMpgdUKBTDhojs7OIyNsZAhTGgAIwwpAADwWUxAECCOARAF8cVJrvY7iAHnAAMIwdJQgafIzfNAGeFLED-cSA4HiUGYcFISHQkCwjSM5nIVGoJkyTHxXH4wm3HYmcwAEXamF53hpXzuADZtX8AWgOVyeXyBoKFkixUz0VLseK8QBdGSyJBqy5y4mkgD6LrdHy151QVxJRJ2OgAcqGZJhwjhPfp+fDAeNZSH5VptAA1LLhRoSFKR+XR2Px+QDJO4h2pm7E4JQn2ulD+ukKd0YqJeO7otWKKHc+1Vp0C9JmQPBmNxnYQcIIJhsIwDGs7UnvEBuRRsBCGuSN5cJhtu-EgOClBPbk9BRTbtw0IwLoEgWn09BSuBGHr0o-rLbbo4ne8gAATNoABUNRPC8bygeBcDPFYbwgF+lKTg+T7EhAACODDpNsR6YGw85qHaoA3m+gJprheLRhCEAeIoW5BqAE7EnRGoyHQWSuuogYAMzMpiXFQL+sz-jsbinBAuGSiJpxiZ4bFrvJraMYpnY7N44iXgMYqgH+snoEM9AEIBiEyOEwnHPpGBwLMWDGYhqascSUDziYZYyHY8GBrpMkAaScGvOcVEkUpy5zrI5mSpgJRkCMD56X5CYUlS1RgUyDkEqpGroIqZgDLlgbHrI9a+k2ciquqdw+ZZAG5SqAmlJRg6psxOx7CMMjrpu26lTsdZwAeKBHqYl5IEkpBoOJZxwDIJ4uWWD4MDgvpVRi0VsGYq1oTsADEBRCV+62bQA6jQwwwNu22oOMlACHieE0XRDHjiWCqmGY7UXR5cBYTQ-gWaJ6BOaZGLIcSir8mIRTeAAGjsvoMAglBQ52lCopKHbeAAmvDrqI8jmNwJQkUgD2fZw+gCNI2TcCYGjAw05gOOU3j1MpXT5k4lWmWtegQTItynUbgxoC9fcCZBexmmceNdxTZJs3S1eD43nel1ajsPRjXlR4eJpADKmxbRr4opkec1noty2uqt5kqzQZE7CTbBuG4kn9tVgMkgmAVQWBBg3fCGUgDpa4O0Y5GonhcAC9e4fkVTlBLkepwierLbqReWQOY6OJAA) to my code.

N.B: I tried using rect marks, whose widths are easier to modify. But the aesthetics of the rect mark do not work for my use case. My use case is a [Force Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/force/) force-directed graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example using your Vega spec with Force transform and text box using reactive geometry as suggested by David.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAE4tvIC0AGxriA1ttk0kZRUgTaA7nRjaAZm0VQ4Bq4rhQmHCy2kZIAJ5sDJhSlnA4NIGmZNqwSHaBcIqpbAZsUFAMiv7i3tqm2vRwumykRtoAMgraALI0EACXdkxGCpTSIM6y9GgCAAxjMvA0ZFhoAEwTMkjRbBA0AF5waCA4SLID62TiSEYQaADaoCcI2%20h68gBK%20zQM5zLEpwx34zJMpgdUKBTDhojs7OIyNsZAhTGgAIwwpAADwRSxAECCOARAF8cVJrvY7iAHnAAMIwdJQgafIzfNAGeHo-7iQHA8SgzDgpCQ6EgWEaRno5Co1BMmSY%20K4-GE247EzmAAi7UwPO8NK%20dwAbFq-gC0OzOdzeQMBaMkaKmZMMVjpQSSUSdkFkZgAAr7KyQjV0n561kGkAgsHoCHUmFw1DWkULa2S7FivH2m7EqCecRZZ5WN7e%20li60stmBjnBkChvlmyMWmMS20JmUOuXoCAwNiOADK4QQTDYRhzdzcpwgcD9haDXPQsACZm7qLxAF0ZLIkKrLrLiaSAPpLlcfTXnVBXBvEnQAOUdMkw4Rw6-0fPhgLG9eTOx0ADUsuFGhIUme5Rerze8gDPeuJzk%20jroMEUJbsuKC7j6%206HmIRTqpWICqooULjvCOJgQu-LpGYiGgJe147BAnbdr2MjPvct7vCAbiKGwCABtuKB0fIMErviIBwKUt4BgwODbncoBuDQRi9kCIC0rmIC2HA4QgLxbB7FAdDKTJRwnNJGItu2lE9toAD82hjJQAjaKg5kqRKmxiRiMy6TsroAJLaAAVDUTwvG8Xk%20XAmavOcvHNkgZEyXJKY0F4vQqYm6EQhAHiKKxB4kQBOypeqMh0Fky7qPuADM6KYoVUABjppzZYO2xhc5NXoDlfItcRjGeKhIDeOIQSKAMoqgNVelDPQBDzHZIBaUNjV6dMsyYONCX2i1OyplJNBATIdhZvuM3HE1JK3sF2aJuJnXrt2sjKTWJRkCM2mzTspIUlS1TeUyy3nV4xIKmYAx-fufGyNB7EDFY5WlI5w3yqYZjKpD6rzrh9akcSewjDITEsWxsE7FBcDcSgvGmH1SBJKQaADmcw58QJQEycJolVZgzFmI50U7AAxAUlVhazbDswA6ptD2gJzkaWXivGszyKWeOlh5o7D5gYzAAz%20AAjgwsXQ09zUXZN4WRSACp8shP0ABo7NuDAIJQFveJQqISlEP0AJo28udsO27Ts3ehb2YNb6C2-bGFYc7AwR3AmCe6H3vh0HlDKSj9rK%20gzpcjREHoXALrIIo-1Y8x6WgGDnEKJNpMFRT-Z1TI-GpgzoD8X1AYSVJAYSyAPTk-9vEeL1bYOd3moIlqiVM8ujnTYxNBwEYgJTQMbBuG4Q7jvtLmVydEABQYFnwstICDfPi-L7OF751v59L17mA%208%20vGnM5Y8%20mtbdZJNTBIEOZvv3krCWQsh4rSxkBsAE%20dcRJlzv4QIhdi7oSyiGAI2dGKl1xiuTON9EGTSboJRmIkZ4BjPhJC%20OxuwMFZBAZ2x9tpRH9KgVm3wZBrw3rHKq%20sQAGCzu6EByQT7IgmjJch990BUJoc7CaDDqGAhYbTdhm8uEHT0nwj0gjEpzzEcvSRshaHhHoaWRh8jFCsJAEozhj1VE7F4TffhnoyAn3CCI8SC9xG9xMQYmRxi5FoAUWw9eyjrE7zzi6BxmjeKpkUOmRQe8VGhOibE%20Jg9JLSXFuPdAr9vA9HpPzNmHNMk2jgIvXJ9VpZgSAA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 200,
  "autosize": "pad",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "nodeRadius",
      "value": 50,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 100, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeCharge",
      "value": -100,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -100, "max": 10, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "linkDistance",
      "value": 66,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "textPadding", 
      "value": 5,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 20, "step": 1}
      },
    {
      "name": "cornerRadius", 
      "value": 10,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 20, "step": 1}
    },
    { "name": "showSymbol", "value": false, "bind": {"input": "checkbox"} },

  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "node_data",
      "values": [
        {"name": "A Name", "type": "node", "1d": 0},
        {"name": "A Very Long Name", "type": "node", "1d": 1}
      ]
    },
    {"name": "edge_data", "values": [{"source": 0, "target": 1}]}
  ],
  "marks": [
   {
      "type": "symbol",
      "name": "nodes",
      "from": {"data": "node_data"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "grey"},
          "opacity": {"signal": "showSymbol ? 0.5 : 0"},
          "size": {"signal": "PI * nodeRadius * nodeRadius"},
          "shape": {"value": "circle"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "force",
          "iterations": 300,
          "static": {"signal": "false"},
          "signal": "force",
          "forces": [
            {
              "force": "center",
              "x": {"signal": "width/2"},
              "y": {"signal": "height/2"}
            },
            {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "nodeRadius"}},
            {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge * 10"}},
            {
              "force": "link",
              "links": "edge_data",
              "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "edge_data"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {"stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}, "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "require": {"signal": "force"},
          "shape": "line",
          "sourceX": "datum.source.x",
          "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
          "targetX": "datum.target.x",
          "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "textmark",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "interactive": false,
      
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"fill": {"value": "black"}, "fontSize": {"value": 16}},
        "update": {
          "y": {"field": "y", "offset": {"signal": "nodeRadius * -0.1"}},
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "text": {"field": "datum.name"},
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
        }
      },
       "zindex": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "rectmark",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "textmark"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "bounds.x1", "round": true,  "offset": {"signal": "-textPadding"}},
          "x2": {"field": "bounds.x2", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "textPadding"}},
          "y": {"field": "bounds.y1", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "-textPadding"}},
          "y2": {"field": "bounds.y2", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "textPadding"}},
          "cornerRadius": {"signal": "cornerRadius"},
          "fill": {"value": "aliceblue"},
          "stroke": {"value": "steelblue"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Roy for this answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. I could have made everyone's jobs easier with a more descriptive question. But you resolved my issue nonetheless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you're asking. Do you mean just increase the size of the symbol statically like this?

[image]

If so, just put a value in the size property.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "autosize": "pad",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "nodeRadius",
      "value": 50,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 50, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeCharge",
      "value": -100,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -100, "max": 10, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "linkDistance",
      "value": 66,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "node_data",
      "values": [
        {"name": "A Name", "type": "node", "1d": 0},
        {"name": "A Very Long Name", "type": "node", "1d": 1}
      ]
    },
    {"name": "edge_data", "values": [{"source": 0, "target": 1}]}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "name": "nodes",
      "from": {"data": "node_data"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
          "size": {"value": 10000},
          "tooltip": {"field": "name"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "force",
          "iterations": 300,
          "static": {"signal": "false"},
          "signal": "force",
          "forces": [
            {
              "force": "center",
              "x": {"signal": "width/2"},
              "y": {"signal": "height/2"}
            },
            {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "nodeRadius"}},
            {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge * 10"}},
            {
              "force": "link",
              "links": "edge_data",
              "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "edge_data"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {"stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}, "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "require": {"signal": "force"},
          "shape": "line",
          "sourceX": "datum.source.x",
          "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
          "targetX": "datum.target.x",
          "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "interactive": false,
      "enter": {"fill": {"value": "black"}, "fontSize": {"value": 10}},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"field": "y", "offset": {"signal": "nodeRadius * -0.1"}},
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "text": {"field": "datum.name"},
          "align": {"value": "center"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or you can split the word like this.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A node-link diagram with force-directed layout, depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "autosize": "pad",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "nodeRadius",
      "value": 50,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 50, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "nodeCharge",
      "value": -100,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -100, "max": 10, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "linkDistance",
      "value": 66,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 5, "max": 100, "step": 1}
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "node_data",
      "values": [
        {"name": "A Name", "type": "node", "1d": 0},
        {"name": ["A Very", "Long Name"], "type": "node", "1d": 1}
      ]
    },
    {"name": "edge_data", "values": [{"source": 0, "target": 1}]}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "name": "nodes",
      "from": {"data": "node_data"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"},
          "size": {"value": 10000},
          "tooltip": {"field": "name"}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "force",
          "iterations": 300,
          "static": {"signal": "false"},
          "signal": "force",
          "forces": [
            {
              "force": "center",
              "x": {"signal": "width/2"},
              "y": {"signal": "height/2"}
            },
            {"force": "collide", "radius": {"signal": "nodeRadius"}},
            {"force": "nbody", "strength": {"signal": "nodeCharge * 10"}},
            {
              "force": "link",
              "links": "edge_data",
              "distance": {"signal": "linkDistance"}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "edge_data"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {"stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}, "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.5}}
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "require": {"signal": "force"},
          "shape": "line",
          "sourceX": "datum.source.x",
          "sourceY": "datum.source.y",
          "targetX": "datum.target.x",
          "targetY": "datum.target.y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "interactive": false,
      "enter": {"fill": {"value": "black"}, "fontSize": {"value": 10}},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"field": "y", "offset": {"signal": "nodeRadius * -0.1"}},
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "text": {"field": "datum.name"},
          "align": {"value": "center"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want something dynamic to size the node to the label extent, you have to use [reactive geometry](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/).

Comment: Thank you David for your help. I want the labels to be in a single line and the symbol to dynamically increase its width to accommodate the label. The circle shape is probably the wrong shape for this. I will update the code and the question to make them clearer.

Comment: In that case, you need to use reactive geometry in the link I provided at the end. I'll add another answer for you.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your help. Roy also posted an answer that utilizes reactive geometry, just like you suggested, and It looks exactly like what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Using reactive geometry for you. This example is from [jheer on GitHub.](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1820)
This sets the rectangles width and height according to the text mark.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100,

  "data": [
    {"name": "labels", "values": [{"label": "Text"}]}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "signals": [
        {"name": "bgoffset", "value": 3}
      ],
      "marks": [        
        {
          "name": "textmark",
          "type": "text",
          "from": {"data": "labels"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "text": {"field": "label"},
              "x": {"value": 50},
              "y": {"value": 50},
              "fontSize": {"value": 14},
              "align": {"value": "center"},
              "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
            }
          },
          "zindex": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "rectmark",
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "textmark"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"field": "bounds.x1", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "-bgoffset"}},
              "x2": {"field": "bounds.x2", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "bgoffset"}},
              "y": {"field": "bounds.y1", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "-bgoffset"}},
              "y2": {"field": "bounds.y2", "round": true, "offset": {"signal": "bgoffset"}},
              "fill": {"value": "aliceblue"},
              "stroke": {"value": "steelblue"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```